# How to implement opentelemetry resource in python

Tags: python, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I using a python script to collect some metrics and the collector to send them to new relic, but I have more than 1 host to collect metrics from and for what I did understood I should use resource to separate the metrics by host, but there is nothing in python documentation about the implementation. How should I do it?

I tried create a resource passing the ip address from one of the hosts, but nothing changed, here's how I did it:

```
metrics.set_meter_provider(MeterProvider(resource=Resource.create({"host.ip": "0.0.0.0"})))

metrics.set_meter_provider(MeterProvider(resource=Resource.create({"host.ip": "0.0.0.0"})))
counter = metrics.get_meter('meter').create_counter(
    name="meter",
    description="meter"
)
counter.add(1, {'host': 'HOST', 'value': 1, 'status': 'STATUS'})
```

Even after adding a resource in the provider, nothing changed in the collector debug or in the new relic table.